# gnuplot : 3d plot an electromagnetic wave function

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to do this with gnuplot? Something like on this image (link)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ3M0.gif

I cannot seem to be able to set x = sin(y) and z = sin(y) independently. seeking help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  You're in luck, I figured this out last week.  Here is the gnuplot code I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

reset

set term png lw 2
set out 'test.png'

set style data lines

# Set x,y,z ranges
set xr [0:10]
set yr [-2:2]
set zr [-2:2]

# Rotates so that plots have a nice orientation.
# To get parameters, plot in interactive terminal and use 'show view' command.
set view 45,30,1,1

set arrow from 0,0,0 to 10,0,0

unset border
unset tics

splot '+' u 1:(0):(sin($1))  t 'E', \
      '+' u 1:(-sin($1)):(0) t 'B'
```

And here is the figure I get:

[image]

I don't have labels, but you can use `set label` and more arrows to reproduce your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define curves like this parametrically:

```
set parametric
splot u,0,sin(u) title 'E',\
      u,-sin(u),0 title 'B'
```

Note that the `u` here isn't shorthand for `using` as you'll often see.  `u` is a dummy variable used in parametric "s"plotting by gnuplot.